# How can I access the Nightmare difficulty in the Quake TC "X-Men: The Ravages of Apocalypse"?

Tags: quake

Like the original *Quake*, the player must explore the difficulty selection hub (in this case, the X-Mansion) to find the Nightmare difficulty in the total conversion *X-Men: The Ravages of Apocalypse*. The entrance can be found in the Women's Dormitory section of the X-Mansion, but it is blocked.

How do I open the barriers blocking the 'tube' leading to Nightmare difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

To open the Nightmare difficulty, one must find a small hidden black book in the room named 'The Library'. This is on the ground floor of the X-Mansion, through the rightmost door behind the staircase. The black book is a very small switch found embedded in the bookcase immediately to the player's right as they enter the library. Walk into it and the Nightmare selector in the Women's Dormitory will be opened. If you can't find the book - try running across all the walls of the Library until you find it.

Comment: Posting this as I can't find any mention of it on the internet, except on a Russian-language retrospective of the mod. Hopefully it saves someone a few hours of searching the otherwise uninteractive X-Mansion.